# Casting operator ignored?

Tags: c++

Having such simple code:

```
DWORD i = 0xFFFFFFF5; // == 4294967285(signed) ==  -11(unsigned)

    if((unsigned)i == -11)
      OutputDebugString(L"equal");
    else
      OutputDebugString(L"not equal");
```

The condition is meet - i'm getting "equal" output.

My question is WHY is that happen since in the condition we have
`f(4294967285 == -11)` considering the explicit `unsigned` cast on the left side of the operator? Why is the cast ignored?

Comment: Cast isn't ignored. `-11` is implicitly casted to `unsigned` due to [promotion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions). I had a nice duplicate for that somewhere...

Comment: You forced an unsigned comparison. So why should it be false if they differ only in sign?

Comment: `DWORD` is already unsigned. The cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen. ok but when i change it to `if ((unsigned)iii == (signed)-11)` is STILL returns true("equal")...!?

Comment: `(unsigned)iii == (signed)-11)` compares an `unsigned` value to a `signed` value. `signed` is a synonym for `signed int` and `int`. So it compares an `unsigned` to an `int`. The rules for converting operands are applied, and the `int` is converted to `unsigned`. There is no way in C++ to compare two numbers of different types with the built-in operators. Two operands to `==` are always converted to a common type.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen -- right, except that it's implicitly **converted**. There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. So it's always explicit.

Comment: @darro911 `-11` is already considered an `int` (=`signed`) without the cast. The compiler recognizes that you're applying the operator `==` to operands of type `unsigned` and `signed` resulting in it requiring to convert the `signed` parameter to `unsigned` according to the standard, i.e. it becomes `if (iii == static_cast<unsigned>((signed) -11))` or equivalent  `if (iii == static_cast<unsigned>(-11))`. If you want to compare signed ints, you need to do `if(static_cast<signed>(iii) == -11)`

Comment: You can't compare `unsigned int` and `signed int`. Compiler will always perform promotions to get them to the same type (in this case `unsigned int`), you can't disable that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So in `(unsigned)iii == (signed)-11)` the `(signed)` cast in the left side of `-11` is just ignored?

Comment: @darro911 Yes, -11 is signed already, so casting it to signed has no effect.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Ok so to sum it up - even if the -11 is SIGNED it is automatically and forcefully converted to unsigned(4294967285) and there is NO way to tell the compiler to treat is as signed as it was written in the condition?

Comment: I think you still don't understand that it is not possible to compare `unsigned int` and `int`. They are different types, it's like comparing apples to oranges. They *must* be converted to one and the same type before comparison happens. If you try to compare `unsigned int` and `int`, compiler will always perform promotion before comparing. If you want `4294967285` and `-11` to be unequal, you need to either cast at least one operand to a bigger type (e.g. `(long long)iii == -11`) or find another comparison method (e.g. converting to string representations or converting to floats or something)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Ok, friend I DO understand that it is not possible to compare unsigned int and int. All i said is there is no way to force the compiler to do some counter conversion - convert the `4294967285` to signed (-11) and then compare -11 to -11 instead of converting -11 to unsigned `4294967285`  and then comparing `4294967285`  to `4294967285`  what is indeed  being done?

Comment: You can, if you cast `iii` to `int`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So You mean that in case of `if ((int)i == -11)` the compiler'll  convert `i` to `signed int`: `- 11` and then make a comparison like `-11 ==-11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DWORD` is `unsigned` or equivalent, a 32-bit unsigned integer in your C++ implementation. `DWORD i = 0xFFFFFFF5;` initializes `i` to FFFFFFF5<sub>16</sub> = 4,294,967,285.

In `(unsigned)i == -11`, `i` is converted to `unsigned`, which yields the same value, 4,294,967,285. The other operand, `-11`, has type `int` and value −11.

When two numbers are compared with `==`, they are converted to be some common type. The rules for operating on an `unsigned` and an `int` result in the `int` being converted to `unsigned`. When −11 is converted to `unsigned` in a C++ implementation in which `unsigned` is 32 bits, the result of the conversion is 2<sup>32</sup>−11 = 4,294,967,296 − 11 = 4,294,967,285.

Then the two `unsigned` values are compared. Since they are both 4,294,967,285, the comparison indicates they are equal.